# How to keep a grid static when navigating between pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

Hello I'm wondering how I can go about implementing a way to keep a desired grid or panel in place even when navigating to a new page?

The Xbox Music app for Windows 8.1 does this with its left panel.
The Pandora app for Windows Phone 8 also does this with its logo banner up top.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this with `StackPanel` then you can have multiple StackPanels.you can show one of them at a time as per your code logic, no need to navigate to a `New Page`.Same case for `Grid` and other UI components.

Also, you can have multiple items inside Panorama/Pivot with defined headers.Part above header like image can be a single UI component and will not change as you are just changing Panorama's/Pivot's SelectedItem. Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a root page which will contain your static controls and a frame to contain other pages.

Here's an example of a application bar across pages: [How to share an app bar across pages (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150604.aspx)